# MySQL data in column wise which is stored in row based

Tags: mysql

I am having a table with data stored in row basis as shown below.

```
UID | DetailsID | Data|
----------------------|
 1  |     1     |  A  |
 1  |     2     |  200|
 1  |     3     |  2010-10-11 08:32 |
 2  |     1     |  B  |
 2  |     2     |  600|
 2  |     3     |  2011-05-20 14:56 |
```

From this I need the output as follows

```
UID|1|2|3
------------
1|A|200|2010-10-11 08:32
2|B|600|2011-05-20 14:56
```

Here main thing is, the number of entries of DetailsID values is not known.

I wanted this one in MySQL.

Please help me out of this.

Comment: You want a pivot table, which is not available/automatic in MySQL.

Answer (score 2):

Not quite what you want, but other than loads of left joins i can only suggest:

```
SELECT UID,GROUP_CONCAT(DetailsID SEPARATOR ",") "DetailsIDs",GROUP_CONCAT(Data SEPARATOR ",") "Data" FROM data_table GROUP BY UID;
```

Comment: This is not the one I required, I wanted each DetailsID as a Column and the data for that DetailsID as rows.

Answer (score 2):

Do that transformation in your coding language, not in SQL.

Answer (score 0):

you didnt say where you need the output. If you need the output in PHP pages it is simple only by creating the loop for the entries in columns wise.